# How can I skip key in object loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there is any way to skip key in object loop. If I have:

```
obj = {
   key1 : [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   key2 : [ 4, 5 ],
   key3 : []
}
```

how can I skip, for example, the empty one. Because I want to `join()` the not empty arrays in that object, and filter them. If I join that empty array the filter looks for empty string and of course it doesn't find it, and everything brakes.

```
var match = $('.widget');
for ( var i in obj ){
    var joined = obj[i].join();
    match = match.filter(joined);
}
```

I have tried to delete it:

```
if ( obj[i].length == 0 ) {
    delete obj[i]
};
```

but error occurs that obj[i] is undefined and can't join it. How can I just skip it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [loop control](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm):

```
for (var i in obj) {
   if (obj[i].length == 0) {
       continue;
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the key to delete a property :

```
for ( var i in obj ){
    if ( obj[i].length == 0 ) {
        delete i
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!obj[i] || obj[i].length === 0)` is a bit more robust